# Only first part of long text messages received

Tags: sms

When someone sends me a long text message, I'm only receiving the first part of the message instead of receiving multiple messages.  I am able to consistently reproduce the issue.  When I first brought this up with Verizon support, they had me clear the data for the Messaging application, and then I started receiving all parts of a message.  However, the problem has now come back.  Obviously, I cannot constantly clear the data for the Messaging app, and even doing so does not help the fact that I'm permanently losing the full payload of messages.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and found a *permanent* fix?  Is there a replacement SMS app that works properly?  I've encountered this problem in the past with Android 2.3.3 and now with 2.3.4, both on my LG VS910 4G phone.

Comment: Same issue, still looking for a fix, so far for me only seems and issue when receiving from iphones.

Comment: The problem is occurring for me with non-iPhone senders as well.

Comment: I've found this problem when receiving both vcard (contacts) and vcal (calendar) messages sent from other phones as SMS. Only the subject line ("here's my contact details" for example) is given to the user, the other information is discarded.
samsung galaxy ace, android gingerbread 2.3.6

Comment: In Messaging, hit Menu key > Settings, is the Auto-retrieve checked?

Comment: Seems to be for cross-network SMS only, not a phone issue. Specifically, it seems to be messages from T-Mobile.